# How can infer types from either string or string array property

Tags: typescript

Given the following scenario:

```js
type Action =
| { type: 'FOO' }
| { type: 'BAR' }

type Rule = {
   target: string | string[],
   consequence: (action:Action) => void
}

const rule1:Rule = {
  target: 'FOO',
  consequence: action => console.log(action) // { type: 'FOO' }
}

const rule2:Rule = {
  target: ['FOO', 'BAR'],
  consequence: action => console.log(action) // { type: 'FOO' } | { type: 'BAR' }
}
```

The action can be dispatched (e.g with redux) and the rule can react to it. When the target matches the **action.type** then the consequence gets executed with the matching action.

#### The Question

I want that the rules **consequence** infers the right type. This can be done somehow by the **target**. But I don't know how. My current approach:

```js
type Rule<Action> = {
  target: string | string[],
  consequence: (action:Action) => void
}
const rule:Rule<{ type: 'FOO' }> = ...
```

But I need a way where I can write

```js
const rule:Rule<{ type: 'FOO' } | { type: 'BAR' }> = ...
```

and the correct type gets inferred by the rules **target**

Comment: _"I want that the rules consequence infers the right type. This can be done somehow by the target."_ Can you explain this more? It's not very clear what you want here. Given what input type, are you expecting what output type?

Comment: the input is the action e.g **const action = { type:'FOO' }**. If my rule has **target:'FOO'** or **target: ['FOO']** then the consequence should infer the type from **type Action = {type: 'FOO'} | {type:'BAR'}**. so only **{type:'FOO'}** should remain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I could figure out. You'll have to abandon `target` being a single value, and rely on it always being an array, even if that array has a single element. There might be a way to get it to work with function overloads, but I couldn't get it to work.

```js
type ActionType = "FOO" | "BAR";

type Action<T extends ActionType> = { type: T };

function createRule<T extends ActionType[]>(target: T) {
  return {
    target,
    consequence: (action: Action<T[number]>) => console.log(action)
  };
}

const foo = createRule(["FOO"]);
const bar = createRule(["FOO", "BAR"]);

foo.consequence({ type: "FOO" });
foo.consequence({ type: "BAR" }); // nope
bar.consequence({ type: "FOO" });
bar.consequence({ type: "BAR" });
bar.consequence({ type: "BAZ" }); // nope
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-wildflower-03cbq?file=/src/index.ts

Using a function to create the rule lets you use generics without having to repeat yourself by specifying it as both a type and a value every time you create a new rule.